# How to capture paste event for all worksheets in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help me with the below code I'm trying to capture the paste event to get the selection of the paste in order to remove the space and non printable characters. So basically when I paste I need it to automatically check if I pasted and remove any space and non printable characters from the paste selection this will decrease the time that my macros will process as there will be couple of rows pasted at one given time and it seems logical to me to remove the space and non printable characters in this state whilst the list is small and will not create too much delay. It crashes on me and can't get my head around it.

As always any help will be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim lastAction As String
  'On Error Resume Next
  ' Get the last action performed by user
  lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo")
Debug.Print lastAction
  ' Check if the last action was a paste
  If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then

   Call removeSpace
  End If

End Sub

Private Sub removeSpace()
Dim rngremovespace As Range
Dim CellChecker As Range
Dim rng As Range
'Set the range
Set rngremovespace = Selection
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'This check to see if there are any non printing characters and replace them
   rngremovespace.Select
rngremovespace.Columns.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

     'In case of any error skip
On Error Resume Next
'Looping through a range that is resizing
     For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Columns

     'This will clear all space in the cells
    CellChecker.Value = Application.Trim(CellChecker.Value)
    CellChecker.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CellChecker.Value)

  'Looping to the next CellChecker
   Next CellChecker

    On Error GoTo 0
  ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set rngremovespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing 'rngremovespace.Select', which is likely to trigger the selection_change event again and again

Comment: Do not use `.Select` or `Selection`. Use `target`. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/15/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/) Also for all worksheets, you may want to use `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` in `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Removed it but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs a check if the Undo list is empty, loop cells instead of columns, and disable events (not tested):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo")
        If .ListCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
        If .List(1) <> "Paste" Then Exit Sub            
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Selection.Replace ChrW(160), " ", xlPart
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell.Value2))        
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help just tested and the above code will only clear the space but there is a non printing character when pasting from Outlook to Excel it copys that character as well and it's not space. Basically we sorted only one problem above so there is still the problem with the non printable character that i need to work out how to fix. Again thank you for your help much appreciated.

Comment: @QuickSilver seems like [`.Clean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837762.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1) doesn't replace Unicode spaces or Chr(160), so I added it to the sample. Also, use `AscW` and `ChrW` for Unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help much appreciated it work well this is what i needed the only thing is for some reason after i paste if i select a different cell and hit enter it will paste the same info again any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: @QuickSilver you can try adding `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. I think it might be because VBA clears the Undo buffer, but I can't test it.

Comment: Another question i have is if i put the code in thisworkbook it will be executed for each sheet but what if i have another event in 2 sheets that calc the diff between the dates and it seems i can't paste in those 2 sheets can you provide more info on the matter please? Can you have 2 events one on the sheet and one on thisworkbook and work together?

Comment: i tested `Application.CutCopyMode = False` and works very well thank you very much. If you can let me know about the other question that will be great. Again thank you!

Comment: @QuickSilver I don't understand the other question, but I would recommend to have the events either only in the workbook or the sheets to avoid hard to debug issues like this. Also note that the other events will not trigger after `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: if i move the code from the specific sheet to `thisworkbook` then will i need to change the code to work or reference the sheet to actually work on that specific sheet because i need it to work on 2 specific sheets?

Comment: @QuickSilver yes, you can check if `Target.Worksheet.Name` matches the names of the sheets.